# Adding a new alias to existing dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, alias

So I'm trying to add a new "name" as an alias to an existing key in a dictionary.

for example:

```
dic = {"duck": "yellow"}

userInput = raw_input("Type the *name* and *newname* (alias) here:")

#Somecode that allows me to input newname as an alias to "duck"
```

The user types two words: *name* to reference "duck", and *newname*  a new key that should point to the value of the existing key. Ie an alias.
So when I change the value for `"duck"` the `"newname"` should change too, and vice versa.

I've tried a lot of things but can't figure out a good way to do this.

Comment: Why would you want the user to enter arbitrary name and then use that name as a variable?

Comment: User should enter name because: "name" is what "newname" should point to as an alias. So user might enter: duck plastic. Now plastic also should refer to the value "yellow".

Comment: so `name` is the existing key, and `newname` is a new key to be inserted to the dict and pointing the same value right?

Comment: That is correct @Vinny

Answer (score 11):

There's no built-in functionality for this, but it's easy enough to build on top of the `dict` type:

```
class AliasDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.aliases = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return dict.__getitem__(self, self.aliases.get(key, key))

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        return dict.__setitem__(self, self.aliases.get(key, key), value)

    def add_alias(self, key, alias):
        self.aliases[alias] = key


dic = AliasDict({"duck": "yellow"})
dic.add_alias("duck", "monkey")
print(dic["monkey"])    # prints "yellow"
dic["monkey"] = "ultraviolet"
print(dic["duck"])      # prints "ultraviolet"
```

`aliases.get(key, key)` returns the `key` unchanged if there is no alias for it.

Handling deletion of keys and aliases is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This looks elegant; using aliases dict to original keys is a great solution to this question