# Create a dictionary with "optional keys"

Tags: python, dictionary

I am generating a solution for geographical data.
This involves one ID for each specific location - a key - and also a coordinate pair - also a key - for a specific value.

Depending on the methods I have implemented, it would be nice to access the objects based on ID or coordinates.
One workaround for this would be pointing one the of the keys to the other one.

```
d = dict()
for i in range(100):
    d[i] = i
    d[str(i) + '_aux'] = d[i]
print(d[1], d['1_aux']
```

I don't enjoy having "duplicate" keys for the same value. Is there a pythonic way to replicate this functionality?

Comment: There is an alternative way by subclassing `dict` and replacing the `__getitem__` method in order to transform both keys into the same call. This would have a smaller memory footprint (it will only store each data once instead of twice) but the access time will be slower (as you have to compute the real key from the two possibilites every access). It is always a trade of, in this case between access speed and memory.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405939/adding-a-new-alias-to-existing-dictionary-in-python/46406510#46406510

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.3+ you can use a [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) to implement your own dictionary-like class as shown below. Additional [dictionary-like methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) could be implemented as needed.

```
from collections import ChainMap

class AuxDict:
    @staticmethod
    def aux_key(key):
        return str(key) + '_aux'

    def __init__(self):
        self._mapping, self._aux_mapping = {}, {}
        self._chainmap = ChainMap(self._mapping, self._aux_mapping)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._chainmap.__getitem__(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._mapping.__setitem__(key, value)
        self._aux_mapping.__setitem__(self.aux_key(key), value)


d = AuxDict()
for i in range(10):
    d[i] = i
print(d[1], d['1_aux'])  # -> 1 1
print(d[2], d['2_aux'])  # -> 2 2
# etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problem with creating multiple keys, if multiple keys are what you want. An alternative approach would be a function that would translate coordinates to IDs. Then you could do:

```
locations = dict()

def coord_to_ID(coords):
    # insert suitable code here

locations[coord_to_ID(coords)]
```

Comment: one aspect against duplicate keys: plenty of locations mean that I need to scale. Being able to work within 16gb of mem would be nice here. If for some reason, we want to expand the concept to more than 2 keys, the scale issue becomes more relevant